# How to build Haskell app with a dependencies?

Tags: haskell, sandbox, cabal

I have the Haskell application with some dependencies. A one package from the dependencies contains a bugfix, which wasn't included into the hackage release yet, so I want to install it from github directly.

```
git clone http://github.com/some/repo .deps/repo
cabal sandbox init
cabal sandbox add-source .deps/repo/
cabal install --only-dependencies
cabal build
```

But instead of the successful building I have an error

```
Could not find module `Some.Repo.Module'
```

`.cabal-sandbox` directory contains the file `add-source-timestamps`

```
[("x86_64-linux-ghc-7.6.3",[("/home/user/app/.deps/repo",0)])]
```

but nothing else.

What I'm doing wrong? Maybe I'm missed some steps?

Comment: Looks alright to me. Is it possible to know which repo is it and which module should your program import?

Comment: It is pontarius-xmpp https://github.com/pontarius/pontarius-xmpp/ and I'm trying to import Network.Xmpp.IM

Comment: It works fine for me. Do you have `pontarius-xmpp` in the dependencies of the cabal file of your program?

Comment: Ouch, I thought, than this string must be deleted from the ``.cabal``, when I have added ``pontarius-xmpp`` as source

Comment: @DannyNavarro Yes, you've right, it works fine when I've added ``pontarius-xmpp`` and its dependencies. Can you make an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to import the packages in the sandbox sources, you still need to add them as build dependencies to your cabal file.

This answer is derived from the comments to the question.